# Make embed code have a width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use Appreplica on my website, (basically it embeds stuff for you). It works, but there is no way to shorten the embedded window, my Tweets just flow off the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: How do I link it to the HTML>??

Comment: you can create that div on the fly with JS and then append your code output  into it.

Comment: Really sorry, I don't really know much of anything about coding or anything... just a few basics.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much!